# Wordpress issue, cannot view the website or FTP

Tags: wordpress, connection-timeout

I have just installed a plugin called "All in One" for SEO purposes.
It installed successfully, then I clicked Activate and my WiFi cut out, I connected back to a different WiFi and now I cannot view the website, I also cannot connect to the FTP. Could anyone advise on a fix?

Comment: Which server you’re website running ?

Comment: Sorry Vadivel, I fixed this issue, it was only when wordpress was running on my computer. The cleared the server cache and now it works.